# iPhone memory management

Tags: iphone

Do I need to call `release` here or not?

I am Loading view in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in tableview...

```
EventDetailedViewController *eventDetailedViewController=[[EventDetailedViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventDetailedViewController" bundle:nil];
        eventDetailedViewController.aEventInfo=aEventInfo;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventDetailedViewController animated:YES];
    //  [eventDetailedViewController release];
        eventDetailedViewController=nil;
```

When I need to call `[eventDetailedViewController release];` and when I need not to call `[eventDetailedViewController release]`. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in tableview...

EDIT:

I do have three views when I select it, it loads first nib. From first it loads second nib file. From second it loads third nib file. When I get back from third to second to first, my application crashes... I am thinking it's due to releasing my first view controller.

Comment: Is aEventInfo a UIEvent? If so, EventDetailedViewController's aEventInfo property better [copy the event object, rather than retain it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIEvent).

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) are very simple: every call to alloc/new/copy*/retain must be balanced by a call to auto-/release. Anything (object or code block) that calls the former has ownership; when the owner no longer needs the owned object, release it. `self.navigationController`, for example, will retain a pushed view controller (asserting ownership) until the controller is popped form the navigation controller's stack. The only thing this simple(-istic?) explanation leaves out is when to use [weak references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1044135-BCICCFAE) (necessary to prevent [retain cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000810)).

Since `eventDetailedViewController` is a local variable, it's the code block that owns `eventDetailedViewController`. Since the variable isn't static, the variable will be discarded when the block exits and the block can't make use of the object after that, so the object needs to be released.

Comment: @Outis. I do have Three Views When i select its load first view controller. from first its load's second view from second its load third. when i get back from third to second to first. my application crash.....  I am thinking its due to releaseing the my first view controller....

Comment: - (void)dealloc {
 [categorieArray release];
 [nearbyDetailedViewController release];
 [eventListController release];
    [super dealloc];
}  Now i added it into dealloc method.

Comment: use this line eventDetailedViewController=nil; in unload method

Comment: But you did some thing wrong thats why you got crash.Release of that object performs in same method in which you make object or in dealoc if you declare in .h file.

Comment: @Ishu Now i declared EventDetailedViewController *eventDetailedViewController; In .h file and allocated in .m file. released in dealloc method. and now make in nil in unload method.... Is this flow is perfect.?

Comment: Yes this is good and make this object in viewDidLoad.then you can use this object any where in your .m file.

Comment: @kiran: it's not clear what you're doing ([code](http://sscce.org/) would make it clearer), but it sounds like you're over-releasing an object. We need the exact error and enough code (but just enough, and no more) to be able to reproduce the error. The error message and code should be added to your question or (perhaps in this case) a new question: "Why is this causing a crash?"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're are not going to use eventDetailedViewController (you're setting it to nil), you should release it. The UINavigationController's pushViewController method will retain the object so it won't be released until the navigationController no longer needs it.

Setting it to nil, I believe, is only useful if it is a property that's nonatomic where setting it to nil will release the previous value. Since it's a local variable, you should release it.